# What happens if I change my Preference settings of SharedPreference

Tags: android

what if I have a Code like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",0);
```

And now I am so dumb and set it to (lets say the first release of my app had the above code....now several months later I release it with the code change below on the store)

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",1);
```

So I change the acces of it from 0(private) to 1(world readable) or 2 (world writeable)

Are there now two Preferences? So I have to sets of Preferences with different Key-Value pairs and different read/write visibilities in them but all have the same name/key?!

Thank you

Comment: Check out this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: not really helpfull as I have allready the tab for context, SharedPreference and SharedPreferences.Editor open...to broad answer btw...

Comment: but yeah ok I see the other modes are deprecated....

Comment: nevertheless: what would have happend before API 17?

Comment: if you are testing on emulator why not check it yourself. run your app and check whether 2 files are there or only 1 `in the app data folder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since AFAIK android allocate a linux user to each app to acheive some kind of sandbox environment, my guess is that you only change the underline file linux premissions from private (access to the app's user only) to readable by all other programs, if they can access it they would be able to read it.

Comment: yeah I think also I viewed it in the DDMS under files and there was just 1 File even after changing visibility. But this is odd if you jsut can decide that one time these are private and other time you change them back to public and so on....strange isnt it

Comment: I mean odd by calling a function to retrieve the sharedpref and not by one that says sth like "getSharedPrefsAndSetMode()" lol.....maybe also Android does nothing to visibility but just gives a Reference with the saved visibility who knows....Im not a dev at google....

Comment: its the same as using chmod, as you are the owner of the file, you can change its premission anytime you like